# Redirecting after login not working but works fine after registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I used `php artisan make:auth`. I am changing the email to username for login. 
In login.blade.php i just replaced email with username.

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="name" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Now, i am not getting error message for incorrect credidentals and not redirected to `/home` for correct credidentals, the login page just reloads.
I also added this `'username' => $data['username'],` in create function in RegisterController and It sucessfully redirects to /home after registration but not while login.

I have also override this property in logincontroller: `protected $username = 'username';`

Comment: Are you getting any message when you put {{ print_r($errors) }} in the template? It could be that in tries validating the email field, but that doesn't exists so it doesn't show that error now.

Comment: @JanWytze i got the erro for email but i don't really require this `Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object ( [bags:protected] => Array ( [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object ( [messages:protected] => Array ( [email] => Array ( [0] => The email field is required. ) ) [format:protected] => :message ) ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you override following function?

```
public function username()
```

Located in: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php.

change:

```
public function username()
{
        return 'email';
}
```

To:

```
public function username()
{
        return 'username';
}
```

Also make sure you added the username field in the DB.

Your LoginController should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

}
```

Comment: isn't this function similar to this property `protected $username = 'username';`?

Comment: @Steve No it isn't have a look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.3 you can override the `sendLoginResponse()` method in `LoginController.php`, for example:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: I did it but it still is not redirecting. I used `return redirect('/home');` inside authenticated(). I am trying to change email to username.

Comment: this didn't work either. overriding `username()` worked.